# PHP Generating "ItemCode" with loops

Tags: php

my problem is the next this system is fully working, but I have a problem with it. The `$randarray[$i]` is giving just one number when the loop1, its problem because the `$itemhex` can be 8,16,24,32 char long, but its always splitted so the output is:

```
1E10020F9865140000E000FFFFFFFFFF

1F10020F9865140000E000FFFFFFFFFF

8810020F9865140000E000FFFFFFFFFF

8D10020F9865140000E000FFFFFFFFFF
```

The amount of the rows is okey, but the "random" number is the same in it, how can I fix this to have different random number in it?

If the loop1 and $itemhex is just 8 char long, its okey, or if loop2 etc..
Only problem when the loop or more but the $itemhex is longer than 8 char.

```
<?php
    $loop=1;
    $randarray=array();
    for($i=1;$i<=$loop;){
        unset($rand);
        $rand=rand(100000, 999999);
        if(!in_array($rand, $randarray)){
          $randarray[]=$rand;
          $i++;
        }
    }
    $itemhexzero='0000E000FFFFFFFFFF';
    $items = array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($randarray);$i++) {
       $test = array();
       $itemhex='1E10020F1F10020F8810020F8D10020F';
       $arr2 = str_split($itemhex,8);
       for($k=0;$k<=count($arr2)-1;$k++){
         $test []=$arr2[$k];
         $items []= $test[$k].$randarray[$i].$itemhexzero.'<br>';
       }
    }
    $itemcode=implode("",$items);
    echo $itemcode;
?>
```

Comment: It is always the same random number, because there is only 1 random number in `$randarray`. So what is your question?

Comment: What @Midas says, because the `$loop` variable is `1`, causing the for loop to run only once. Spit out the randarray (`$randarray`) after the first loop to see what's going on